# Are 'per second' Performance Counters measured over a certain period of time?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, perfmon

This may be a very silly question, but when I'm looking at the current value of a 'per second' counter in PerfMon, for example `SQL Statistics\Batch Requests/sec` - how is that value actually measured?

Let's say I use PowerShell's Get-Counter method to return a result for a specific server, as follows:

```
(Get-Counter -ComputerName $server -counter $countername -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 1).CounterSamples.CookedValue
```

And this returns: 32

How can that value actually be contextualized? Is it an "average of 32 batch requests per second in the last `x` minutes"? Or is it "in the last second there were 32 batch requests"

Answer (score 0):

It is like it says, per second. Great explanation of what constitutes a 'batch' here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/02/what-is-batch-requests-per-second/